# Project Euler no. 2

Tags: java

I took many stabs at it and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. That is one of my most recent attempts at a solution.

I know the correct answer from other sources is `4613732`.

```
/*
 *             PROBLEM 2
 * Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. 
 * By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
 *
 * 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
 *
 * By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four 
 * million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.
 */

public class problem2 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int sum = 0;

        int[] anArray = new int[4000000];
        anArray[0] = 1;
        anArray[1] = 2;

        for (int i = 2; i <= anArray.length - 1; i++) {
            anArray[i] = anArray[i - 1] + anArray[i - 2];

            if (anArray[i] % 2 == 0 && anArray[i] <= 4000000) {
                sum += anArray[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your program printing out? Do you have any info about what the error is?

Comment: Hint: Try using a `long` type, implementing this without an array, every third expression is even so you don't need to check that.

Answer (score 1):

You're exceeding the precision of an `int`. You're calculating way too many numbers, and eventually get negative numbers. Make the size of your array something sane (like 40), or make a check in your if statement to ignore negative numbers.

Actually, just change the size of the array to 40, since anything after int flips is wrong.

```
int [] anArray = new int[40];
```

Also note that you are not adding the `2`, the second number in your array.

You can also just break out of the for loop when your numbers exceed 4,000,000, since you don't care about them anyways.

Comment: No he's not. The fibonacci numbers will exceed 4 million long before reaching the int overflow limit (over 2 billion).

Comment: Hey, OP here.  When I set the array size to 40 instead of 4 million it gives me the right answer off by 2!!  and that 2 can be found from adding anArray[1] = 2

Comment: @user23463 When I try your code with it set to 40, I get 4613730, which is missing the `2` from the 2nd number (you said the correct answer was 4613732)

Comment: I edited my previous post, yes I made a mistake by saying it was off by 3.  It is off by 2 my answer because I started my loop at the 2nd index.

Comment: @user23463 So you just need to initialize `sum` to 2 instead of 0.

Comment: Oops, I misread it. He isn't breaking out of the loop, which means that he would get overflow.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing the two
Second, to avoid issues with overflow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow, you should insert a break statement as soon as it goes over a million.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=2;i<=anArray.length-1;i++){
            anArray[i]=anArray[i-1]+anArray[i-2];

            if(anArray[i]%2==0 && anArray[i]<=4000000){
                    sum+=anArray[i];
            }
        }
```

You should check the limit of Fibonacci numbers in the loop, not just in the "sum" part. Because you are missing the check, you overflowed. After the overflow, the number "wrapped" back to smaller numbers, causing them (possibly, but definitely here) to be smaller than 4000000.

You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to avoid overflow here. It does not have great performances (at least for Java 1.6), but it'll work with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The logic looks correct to me, however it is an inefficient approach. Project Euler is designed to make you figure out better algorithms, so it is likely that your naive algorithm is running out of time or memory.

Try looking for patterns in the fibonacci numbers to come up with a faster approach.

Edit: I missed that you aren't breaking out of the loop after reaching 4000000. In this case the numbers will overflow and give you incorrect results. You need to break after the numbers exceed 4000000. Also, that huge array is completely unnecessary since you only need the last two numbers to calculate each new number.

Comment: Should I not be using arrays?  I'm going to try it tomorrow again when I have more energy.

Comment: You don't need an array at all because fibonacci numbers only depend on the previous two numbers. So you can get by with just two variables.

Comment: Yes, I've seen a few solutions using what you describe.  I'm definitely going to look into how I could have come up with a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array instead of writting some formula for the sum makes the solution of the problem very ordinary.You can simply use the equal to arithmatic operator, smartly to avoid using an array.
My code solution is like this. Hope it helps you.

```
       /*PRoject euler problem2*/
       /*Sum of even terms in fibonacci sequence*/
           public class Euler2
             {

                static long fibosum()
                 {
                    long sum=0;
                    long initialint=0;
              long secondint=1;
              long fibo=initialint+secondint;
                while(fibo<4000000)
                  {
                    if(fibo%2==0)
                {
                  sum=sum+fibo;
                }
                         initialint=secondint;
                   secondint=fibo;
                   fibo=initialint+secondint;
                        }
             return sum;
               }
             public static void main(String args[])
              {
                 Euler2 a=new Euler2();
           System.out.println("Sum of even fibonacci numbers below 4000000 is"+a.fibosum());
               }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you observe the fibonacci sequence, every third number is a even number:

1,1,**2**,3,5,**8**,13,21,**34**

So an array of length 3 will suffice. We can generate the next 3 fibonacci numbers and store it(overwrite) in the array, the sum of all the third elements(even fib number) in the array will give us the sum of all even numbers in the fibonacci sequence.

Code:

```
public class Prob2 {
    public static int sumOfEvenFibonacci(int limit){
        int fibonacci[] = {1, 1, 2}; 
        int j, sum = 2;

        while(fibonacci[2] < limit){
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                fibonacci[j] = fibonacci[(j+1)%3] + fibonacci[(j+2)%3];
            }
            sum += fibonacci[2];
        }
        return sum - fibonacci[2];
    }
}
```

Trivial test cases:

```
public class TestProb2 {

@Test
public void testSumOfMultiples(){
    int actual = Prob2.sumOfEvenFibonacci(15);
    assertEquals(10, actual);

    actual = Prob2.sumOfEvenFibonacci(50);
    assertEquals(44, actual);

    actual = Prob2.sumOfEvenFibonacci(200);
    assertEquals(188, actual);

    actual = Prob2.sumOfEvenFibonacci(4000000);
    assertEquals(4613732, actual);
}
```

}

P.S: This answer may not exactly answer the OP's question but wanted to share the technique out of joy of finding it. Hope it helps others who land here looking for a solution.